# wrong time shown in admin for registration in Django?

Tags: django, django-settings, django-timezone

I just `registered` for a `new user account` using `Django Admin` but it gives the time of `registration` wrong. It must be `March 24, 2014, 11.01 a.m`.but it shows as `March 24, 2014, 6:01 p.m`.
I am in `PST time-zone`.

In my `settings.py`, I have

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your timezone settings to:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'US/Pacific'
```